# Are the clients in Restify any use in a browser environment?

Tags: json, node.js, api, restify

I'm confused as to the purpose of the clients in Restify:

http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#JsonClient

They are themselves built on Node.js, just as the server bit is. Do I take this to mean they are NOT intended to be used in a browser? Are they really for server to server communication?

If so, how are people implementing their client side (browser) JS code for making calls to Restify APIs? Making GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests directly, or using some other tools?

Comment: Is this still true as of 2024?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, as restify clients are part of restify, they are intended to be used in node.

In addition to **consuming another REST-api** from a node application, the clients are useful in **testing REST-apis**.

For example, I am using mocha and a restify-client as a simple means to drive the development of my api.

To use the restify client, the target api does not have be built upon restify.